# How to suppress a Python AttributeError?

Tags: python, error-handling, attributeerror, arcpy

When I run the ArcGIS Pro [Add Geometry Attributes (Data Management)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-geometry-attributes.htm) command:

```
arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management()
```

I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

AttributeError: 'ToolValidator' object has no attribute 'isLicensed'
```

The tool performs what it needs to do and is working properly. However, doing a little research shows that this is a [known bug](https://community.esri.com/thread/237842-attributeerror-toolvalidator-object-has-no-attribute-islicensed-message) and should be ignored:

> Yes, given that there is no license requirement for the tool
> (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/table-to-excel.htm#L_)
> just ignore and move on.  I've pinged the gp team to make sure they
> can take a look at this recently reported issue.  I apologize you're
> running into it, but looks like it isn't major...

Is there any way to completely suppress an `AttributeError` such as this so I do not see the error in my larger workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run a [`try-except`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp) block around the line of code where the error is to be ignored.

```
try:
    arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management()
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

This will ignore the error and continue on.

Given it seems the error may be in the module, you could just use `except:` however this will ignore every error returned.

Comment: Strangely, wrapping the tool in a `try-except` block still results in the attribute error output.

Comment: In my case, I still get the attribute error because of a missing connection to the database. Therefore all other elements in the module err with an attribute error.